# ASP.NET MVC, view not referencing the correct model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error when rendering a partial view and I'm not sure why as I'm passing through the pagination property as my model.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'StockManager.ViewModels.StockManagementViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'StockManager.ViewModels.Shared.PaginationViewModel'.

Here's the model...

```
public class StockManagementViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<StockReportParentRowsViewModel> StockLevels { get; set; } = new List<StockReportParentRowsViewModel>();

    public PaginationViewModel StockLevelsPagination { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<Int32, String> Full_Site_List { get; set; } = HelperMethods.GenericHelpers.GetFullSiteList();
}
```

And here is where I pass `PaginationViewModel` instance into the partial view:

```
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_PaginationPartial.cshtml", Model.StockLevelsPagination); }
```

Finally, here's the view model reference for the pagination view.

```
@model StockManager.ViewModels.Shared.PaginationViewModel
```

`StockManagementViewModel.StockLevelsPagination` is definitely an instance of `StockManager.ViewModels.Shared.PaginationViewModel` so what gives? What have I missed?

Comment: You are passing Model.StockLevelsPagination. Where do you initialize this variable?

Comment: That's it, the test case I'm using doesn't reach the constructor for it, thanks. That's not as helpful error message, I'd have thought it would say null reference or something instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this happens if the value you're passing is null. So if the property X.Y is null, it just gives up and passes X, then throws this exception.